# iOS 7.1 OTA Install Fails "Cannot Connect to <url>"

Tags: ios, deployment, ios7.1

I've searched the interwebs/SO far and wide and I'm having no luck.

- Server is running IIS 6;
- .ipa mime type is set to application/octet-stream;
- .plist mime type is set to application/xml;
- Server has valid Godaddy certificate installed.

The link `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmyserverurl.com%2Fiosclient%2Fmysoftware.plist` fails to install on iOS 7.1 devices. It's set to https. If I set that link to http, my phone running iOS 7.0.4 downloads and runs the application just fine. If I set the manifest to use https, both devices show the error "Cannot connect to myserverurl.com". I have tried setting the link to the IPA file in the manifest to both http and https but I am having no luck at all.

I made sure that I can put both the plist and ipa URLs in the address bar of my browser and they are both completely accessible.

Any ideas? I've been playing with this for a couple hours now and I'm not having any success.

Comment: are you sure you're using a proper cert? If it's self-signed, you probably added it to your desktop browser's cert store and it'll act like it's a proper cert, but your idevice will properly reject it as invalid.

Comment: It's a valid Godaddy SSL cert.

Comment: ok then... maybe network topology. if the idevices are going over cellular data, and your server is firewalled or on a private IP block, then they won't be able to reach it

Comment: The URL is exposed over the internet. What's weird is that I just tried deploying my plist file to dropbox and it worked, so I'm wondering if iOS has the Godaddy root G2 cert installed.

Comment: try hitting the url in the idevice safari. it'd use the same cert store. if it fails in there, you'd at least get told why.

Comment: I hit the base URL and it worked, no warnings and shows the lock icon in the URL bar. So confused!

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why you may see the "Cannot Connect to " error; however, one other thing to check are the file permissions on your server. Specifically, right click on the folder which holds your IPA and plist and choose properties, then go to security. Add the "Everyone" user and assign full rights to it. If that resolves your issue, you can then "backpedal" to a more secure, but functional user/file permission configuration of your choosing.